# Command design pattern and user interaction

Tags: c++, ios, windows, design-patterns, command-pattern

I am implementing command design pattern but my command needs to ask user for file name. I am not sure how can command ask for it?

The gang of four book seems to touch this issue but I am not quite clear. Below is my code (pseudo code to be correct and written on fly).

```
class OpenDocumentCommand : public Command
{
    virtual char * AskUserForFileName();
    virtual void Execute();

    Application _App;
}

void OpenDocumentCommand::Execute()
{
   char * fileName = AskUserForFileName();

   _App.OpenDocument( fileName );
}
```

Now in typical simple example, `AskUserForFileName()` can be `cin` and `cout` but how can it ask for file name in a proper Windows application? It should open File Explorer and user can select file name?

Does it means it has to be tighly coupled with windows? My plan is to use this code both on Windows and iOS so I would like a decoupled solution.

Comment: Just ask for the filename in a separate dialog before, and pass it to your command as parameter.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ But that would sort of mean half of the command is executed outside the command. One of the goals of command is to package and execute the command later.

Comment: _'to package'_ what should this actually mean? IMHO commands should be configured with all of the parameters they'll need to execute, without further interaction.

Comment: 'Does it means it has to be tigh[t]ly coupled with windows?' If you want to separate the GUI code from your command, use the *layers pattern* with the GUI in the presentation layer. This is akin to the View and Controller in MVC.

Answer (score 0):

To minimize coupling between your command and the window you should at least insert an abstraction layer between them. In many MVVM implementations you can find a "Modal Dialog"-interface that hides the implementation details of the window from the calling ViewModel.

This interface contains at least a single method "ShowDialog()", but it can also take a ViewModel as a parameter and returns a callback to inform the caller when it gets closed by the user.

Here is an example:

```
public interface IModalWindow
2   {
3     bool? DialogResult { get; set; }
4     event EventHandler Closed;
5     void Show();
6     object DataContext { get; set; }
7     void Close();
8   }
```